# What would be the correct syntax to add the 'alt' attribute in Shopify?

Tags: html, shopify, alt

I am trying to add `alt` text to my images, however, I am a bit confused because of syntax. Basically, every website says to do

```
img src=logo.png alt="Something.com | The best something ever"
```

However, because I was building on Shopify, my code looks like this:

```
img src="{{ '3Y9C5514.jpg' | asset_url }}"
```

I'm a noob so the brackets and the `"| asset_url"` are confusing me. Where should I be including the `alt="my alt text"`?

Comment: I've never personally used Shopify, but I doubt that this would prevent alt text applied normally with an alt attribute from working.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way you put your alt text with image URL.

```
<img src="{{ '3Y9C5514.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Alt text goes here"/>
```

**"|asset_url"** returns the URL of a file in the "assets" folder of a theme. So, if your image file is present in the folder it will fetch the image url.

```
#Input
{{ '3Y9C5514.jpg' | asset_url }}

#Output
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0087/0462/t/394/assets/3Y9C5514.jpg?28253
```

However, if you are inserting an image my suggestion would be to use - **"| asset_img_url"**. This will return the asset URL of an image in the "assets" folder of a theme. **asset_img_url** accepts an image size parameter.

```
#Input
{{ 'logo.png' | asset_img_url: '300x' }}

#Output
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0000/0001/t/1/assets/logo_300x.png?42
```

Source: [URL Filters](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters)